# excel date time formula issue

Tags: excel, date, time, formula

I'm struggling to make a formula work in excel.

My case : I have data in m/d/yyyy h:mm AM/PM format on E col.
I have data that goes to the next day post midnight. I'm looking to create another column lets say F where I want to check for data between time 5:30pm to next day 5:30am and return date in m/d/yyyy(col F)

Example :
Let's say a job request came in at 3/21/2021 4:30am, I want it to return 3/20/2021 on col F (previous date)

This is required due to different timezone and unfortunately the timezone cannot be altered on the data.

Comment: What formula have you tried? I think a simple iif to determine when to subtract a day would be fine but if this is just a timezone issue there are built in functions for that

Answer (score 0):

If it's really true that your data are in "m/d/yyyy hh:mm PM format" then this formula will deduct 8 hours from the value found in E4 and return a true date.

```
=DATE(RIGHT(LEFT(E4,FIND(" ",E4)-1),4),LEFT(E4,FIND("/",E4)-1),MID(E4,FIND("/",E4)+1,1+ISERROR(FIND("/",MID(E4,LEFT(E4,FIND("/",E4)-1),2)))))+TIMEVALUE(MID(E4,10,10))-(8/24)
```

A "True" date is a number which takes its display format from the cell format you set, meaning the "data" are different from the display. A "Fake" date (my expression) is a text string that looks like a date but is unsuitable for calculations because it's not a number. The "data" underlying a fake date are identical to the display. My above formula spends 95% of its effort on converting the fake date into a true one and is likely to earn your comment that it "doesn't work" because it returns a number. If so, don't comment. Set the cell format to the kind of display you want.

Of course, if E4 has a true date the effort can be reduced and the formula you seek would be simply

```
=E4-(8/24)
```

This is because in Excel dates one day has a value of 1. Therefore 1 hour = 1/24 and 8 hours = 1/24*8 or 8/24. Change the number of hours as desired, add or subtract them from the original as needed.

BTW, if your original data are really text (fake dates) do consider converting them to true dates using the 95% part of my first formula and then processing them as true dates. As you see, there is no advantage in keeping fakes around.